# Entering YouTube fullscreen with stereoscopic 3D makes whole display reddish

Tags: google-chrome, drivers, graphics-card, youtube

I am using nVidia 3D Vision, If I watch a normal Video on YouTube and enter fullscreen mode, then my monitor first gets black for about two-three seconds and then after it everything is reddish until I restart my computer.

I already uninstalled my graphics driver with DDU (Display Driver Uninstaller) and installed the newest driver after it. But the problem still occurs often.

I am using chrome, my monitor is from ASUS VG248QE and I am using a GTX 970.
Can someone tell me what I can try to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deactivating stereoscopic 3D in the Nvidia settings and activating it again.

[image: stereoscopic]

It seems like some applications do not recognize if they were ended and stay in 3D mode. But I wonder why it even goes into 3D mode on normal 2D videos?

However, I am not alone with this problem:
https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/514905/asus-vg278h-stuck-in-3d-mode/